# Подскажите метод получения json строки через post запрос

Tags: php, php7

Мне нужно получить и обработать json строку через post запрос, подскажите универсальный метод

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй вот это:

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: спасибо большое)